# Desired font in Thymeleaf document is not shown

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am using a Thymeleaf template for generating an HTML page that is then used as the content of an email. The desired font family is Calibri. When the HTML document is generated however (and then sent as an email) the retrieved email containing this document doesn't contain the font in Calibri.

If I remove the Thymeleaf-related elements and launch the page as a normal HTML page in the browser, however, it does show the content in Calibri. Where might the problem be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title></title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri'
      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
      <style>
         body {
            font-family: 'Calibri', serif;
            font-size: 11pt;
         }
     </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="line-height:25pt;">
        We from <span th:text="${nameCompany}"></span> are sending you an email.
   </p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should play around with the syntax of the code. sometimes tyhmleaf does not accept the syntax that the browser understands.

Comment: Did you try the solutions provided?

Answer (score 2):

can you try changing this line of code and tell me if this helped

change

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri'
      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

to

```
  <link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri}"
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Comment: This didnt work for me.